# Android - Update view outside a custom control (from inside custom control)

Tags: android

I have a custom control with buttons (image) that should update an activity (fragment) control (big 0 string).

May be it is too simple but I don't know how to do it because onClickListener buttons are inside the custom control class. Which is the best approach?

[image]

Listener inside custom control class is:

```
binding.counterSelectorViewPrevious.setOnClickListener(OnClickListener {
        decreaseValue()}

fun decreaseValue() {
    if (mSelectedIndex > 0) {
        val newSelectedIndex = mSelectedIndex - 1
        setSelectedIndex(newSelectedIndex)
    }
}
```

Activity control is just a TextView outside of custom control class.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/workout_length"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display2"
        tools:text="99:99:99" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please can you add some more detail to your question and also the code you currently have.

Comment: Sure, I have updated the post, let me know if I'm still unclear.

Comment: What happens inside the `decreaseValue` function?

Comment: Just decreases the number between image buttons, all of that is a part of custom control, I have updated the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to accept a listener in your custom view what get's some callback from your activity/fragment

something like this

```
private OnValueChangeListener onValueChangeListener;
public void addOnValueChangeListener(OnValueChangeListener onValueChangeListener)
{
    this.onValueChangeListener = onValueChangeListener;
}
public void decreaseValue() {
    onValueChangeListener.onValueChange(newValue);
}

public interface OnValueChangeListener {
    void onValueChange(int newValue);
}
```

then you need to add invoke this somewhere in your activity/fragment (like in onCreate/onCreateView)

```
void setupListener() {
    addOnValueChangeListener(newValue -> {
        findViewById(R.id.workout_length).setText("" + newValue);
    });
}
```

Comment: Exactly, thank you. It took me some time to understand it but this is it. I found this useful link where it is explained: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Creating-Custom-Listeners